# jsch library authentication failure with rsa-sha2-512 preauth failure

Tags: jsch, ssh-tunnel

I am using https://github.com/mwiede/jsch library to establish ssh tunnel. The key is rsa and the handshake and host key verification is working fine. But the authentication is failing for rsa-sha2 algorithms.

```
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:18.766Z    SshUtils$1#log  ssh_ecdsa_verify: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 signature true
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:18.790Z    SshUtils$1#log  Host '[f****.****-staging.com]:2222' is known and matches the ECDSA host key
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:18.791Z    SshUtils$1#log  SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:18.791Z    SshUtils$1#log  SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:18.803Z    SshUtils$1#log  SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:18.806Z    SshUtils$1#log  SSH_MSG_EXT_INFO received
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:18.807Z    SshUtils$1#log  server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:18.809Z    SshUtils$1#log  SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:18.822Z    SshUtils$1#log  Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:18.825Z    SshUtils$1#log  Next authentication method: publickey
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:18.856Z    SshUtils$1#log  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms = ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:18.857Z    SshUtils$1#log  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms in server-sig-algs = [ssh-ed25519, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521, rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256, ssh-rsa, ssh-dss]
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:18.863Z    SshUtils$1#log  rsa-sha2-512 preauth success
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:19.501Z    SshUtils$1#log  rsa-sha2-512 auth failure
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:19.505Z    SshUtils$1#log  rsa-sha2-256 preauth success
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:19.677Z    SshUtils$1#log  rsa-sha2-256 auth failure
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:19.690Z    SshUtils$1#log  ssh-rsa preauth failure
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:19.690Z    SshUtils$1#log  Authentications that can continue: password
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:19.696Z    SshUtils$1#log  Next authentication method: password
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:19.746Z    SshUtils$1#log  Disconnecting from f****.****-staging.com port 2222
INFO    main    2023-10-12T16:13:19.773Z    SshTunnel#createSshTunnel   Auth failed
WARNING main    2023-10-12T16:13:19.774Z    SshTunnel#<init>    Auth Failed
```

When we add ssh-rsa in pubkeyacceptedalgorithms, it works. But we don't want to do that as we don't want to use Sha1. I am unclear on why sha2 based auth is failing.

sha2 algorithm should work for authentication

Comment: Does it work outside of java? Just to exclude a problem with the lib itself...

Comment: When I connect directly from my terminal using ssh client, it works with other algorithms.